# Send Attach file sharepoint 2013 list with web Part C#

Tags: attachments

i want to add attachment file Sharepoint 2013 library but it doesnt work.

here is my code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http//"))
        {
            using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
            {
                oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                // Fetch the List
                SPList list = oSPWeb.Lists["ornekdosya"];
                // Get the List item
                SPListItem listItem = list.GetItemById(1);

                // Get the Attachment collection
                SPAttachmentCollection attachmentCollection = listItem.Attachments;
                Stream attachmentStream;
                Byte[] attachmentContent;
                // Get the file from the file upload control
                if (this.FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    attachmentStream = this.FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

                    attachmentContent = new Byte[attachmentStream.Length];
                    attachmentStream.Read(attachmentContent, 0, (int)attachmentStream.Length);
                    attachmentStream.Close();
                    attachmentStream.Dispose();
                    // Add the file to the attachment collection
                    attachmentCollection.Add(this.FileUpload1.FileName, attachmentContent);
                }
                // Update th list item
                listItem.Update();
                oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }
        }
```

here is my sharepoint list

[image]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you attaching file or uploading file into the document library? attachment and upload or different thing?

Comment: attaching file to document library.

Comment: We can't add an attachment for document library item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above code is used to attach a document to List Item not for Document Library .Please use below code to add to document Library.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http//"))
            {
                using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                    Stream attachmentStream;
                    Byte[] attachmentContent;
                    // Get the file from the file upload control
                    if (this.FileUpload1.HasFile)
                    {
                        attachmentStream = this.FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

                        attachmentContent = new Byte[attachmentStream.Length];
                        attachmentStream.Read(attachmentContent, 0, (int)attachmentStream.Length);

                          SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders["Shared Documents"];

        string fileName=this.FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
                 Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
 SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, attachmentStream , replaceExistingFiles);

        // Commit 
        myLibrary.Update();
         attachmentStream.Close();
           attachmentStream.Dispose();
                    }

                    oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, attachmentStream , replaceExistingFiles);

filename does not exist. why ?

Comment: I think you should use   string fileName=this.FileUpload1.FileName.ToString(); instead of string fileName=fileupload.FileName.ToString(); i will update the answer also

Comment: its work ! ! i success to add but i cant open my file. any help ? i click on my file but doesnt seen anything, nothing. thanks.

Comment: i updated the answer , may be stream is  closed and disposed before File Addition so move attachmentStream.Close();
           attachmentStream.Dispose() after myLibrary.Update();. Then give a try

Comment: I am thankful to you bro ! ! ! ! its work !!!! thanks for helps.. i change dispose and close argument and it work! ! ! ! ! thanks

Comment: no issue. we are here to help and share the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

after this arrangament my code is here sadly it doesnt work :(

```
if (this.FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    attachmentStream = this.FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

                    attachmentContent = new Byte[attachmentStream.Length];
                    attachmentStream.Read(attachmentContent, 0, (int)attachmentStream.Length);
                    attachmentStream.Close();
                    attachmentStream.Dispose();
                    SPFolder myLibrary = oSPWeb.Folders["ornekdosya"];
                    myLibrary.Update();      
                    string fileName;
                    fileName = this.FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
                    Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
                    SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, attachmentStream, replaceExistingFiles);
                    // Commit    
                }

                oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```